# PDF Breaking Display

Tags: pdf, itext

Hi I am having an issue displaying the below html elements in PDF

```
<div class="alternative_name">&##32; &##38754; &##20498; &##144954;</div>

<div class="alternative_name">&##32; &##38754; &##20498;</div>
```

The text from the first div does not show up at all
However the lower one does the only difference is the presence of this character &##144954; ''